# Integer to floating conversion in C

Tags: c, types, printf

```
float f1 = 123.125;
int i1 = -150;

f1 = i1;    // integer to floating conversion
printf("%i assigned to an float produces %f\n", i1, f1);
```

Output:

```
-150 assigned to an float produces -150.000000
```

My question is why the result has 6 zeros (`000000`) after the `.` and not 7 or 8 or some number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just what `printf` does.  See the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) where it says

> `f`, `F`
>
> > The double argument shall be converted to decimal notation in the style "[-]ddd.ddd", where the number of digits after the radix character is equal to the precision specification. **If the precision is missing, it shall be taken as 6**; if the precision is explicitly zero and no '#' flag is present, no radix character shall appear. If a radix character appears, at least one digit appears before it. The low-order digit shall be rounded in an implementation-defined manner.

(emphasis mine)

It has nothing to do with how 150 is represented as a floating point number in memory (and in fact, it's promoted to a `double` because `printf` is varargs).

Answer (score 3):

The number of zeros you see is a result of the default precision used by the `%f` `printf` conversion. It's basically unrelated to the integer to floating point conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Because the C standard (§7.19.6.1) says that in the absence of information to the contrary, `%f` will print 6 decimal places.

> `f,F` A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted to
>   decimal notation in the style *[−]ddd.ddd*, where the number of digits after
>   the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the
>   precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is zero and the # flag is
>   not specified, no decimal-point character appears.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact. `printf` is just showing that number of **zeroes**.

From the documentation:

> The default number of digits after the
>   decimal point is six, but this can be
>   changed with a precision field. If a
>   decimal point appears, at least one
>   digit appears before it. The "double"
>   value is rounded to the correct number
>   of decimal places.

Comment: Why it appended 6 zeros. Not 7 or 8 zeros. The number of zeros based on my hardware?

Comment: @Nano HE: because the standard says "[i]f the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; ..."